# Testing RxJava repeatWhen with Mockk returnsMany

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2, mockk

I'm trying to test multiple server responses with Mockk library. Something like I found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43544670/6387946) for Mockito.

There is my sample UseCase code, which every few seconds repeats call to load the system from a remote server and when the remote system contains more users than local it stops running (`onComplete` is executed).

```
override fun execute(localSystem: System, delay: Long): Completable {
    return cloudRepository.getSystem(localSystem.id)
        .repeatWhen { repeatHandler -> // Repeat every [delay] seconds
            repeatHandler.delay(params.delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        }
        .takeUntil { // Repeat until remote count of users is greater than local count
            return@takeUntil it.users.count() > localSystem.users.count()
        }
        .ignoreElements() // Ignore onNext() calls and wait for onComplete()/onError() call
    }
```

To test this behavior I'm mocking the `cloudRepository.getSystem()` method with the Mockk library:

```
@Test
fun testListeningEnds() {
    every { getSystem(TEST_SYSTEM_ID) } returnsMany listOf(
        Single.just(testSystemGetResponse), // return the same amount of users as local system has
        Single.just(testSystemGetResponse), // return the same amount of users as local system has
        Single.just( // return the greater amount of users as local system has
            testSystemGetResponse.copy(
                owners = listOf(
                    TEST_USER,
                    TEST_USER.copy(id = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                )
            )
        )
    )

    useCase.execute(
        localSystem = TEST_SYSTEM,
        delay = 3L
    )
        .test()
        .await()
        .assertComplete()
}
```

As you can see I'm using the `returnsMany` Answer which should return a different value on every call.

The main problem is that `returnsMany` returns the same first value every time and `.takeUntil {}` never succeeds what means that `onComplete()` is never called for this Completable. How to make `returnsMany` return a different value on each call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably don't understand how exactly `.repeatWhen()` works. You expect `cloudRepository.getSystem(id)` being called every time repetition is requested. That is not correct. Repeated subscription is done all the time on the same instance of mocked `Single` – first `Single.just(testSystemGetResponse)` in your case.

How to make sure, `getSystem()` is called every time? Wrap your Single into `Single.defer()`. It's similar to `Single.fromCallable()` but there is a difference between the return type of passed lambda. Lambda passed to the `.defer()` operator must return Rx type (Single in our case).

Final implementation (I have made a few changes to make it compile successfully):

```kotlin
data class User(val id: String)

data class System(val users: List<User>, val id: Long)

class CloudRepository {
    fun getSystem(id: Long) = Single.just(System(mutableListOf(), id))
}

class SO63506574(
    private val cloudRepository: CloudRepository
) {

    fun execute(localSystem: System, delay: Long): Completable {
        return Single.defer { cloudRepository.getSystem(localSystem.id) } // <-- defer
            .repeatWhen { repeatHandler ->
                repeatHandler.delay(delay, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            }
            .takeUntil {
                return@takeUntil it.users.count() > localSystem.users.count()
            }
            .ignoreElements()
    }
}
```

And test (succeeds after ~8s):

```kotlin
class SO63506574Test {

    @Test
    fun testListeningEnds() {
        val TEST_USER = User("UUID")
        val TEST_SYSTEM = System(mutableListOf(), 10)
        val repository = mockk<CloudRepository>()
        val useCase = SO63506574(repository)
        val testSystemGetResponse = System(mutableListOf(), 10)

        every { repository.getSystem(10) } returnsMany listOf(
            Single.just(testSystemGetResponse), // return the same amount of users as local system has
            Single.just(testSystemGetResponse), // return the same amount of users as local system has
            Single.just( // return the greater amount of users as local system has
                testSystemGetResponse.copy(
                    users = listOf(
                        TEST_USER,
                        TEST_USER.copy(id = UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    )
                )
            )
        )

        useCase.execute(
                localSystem = TEST_SYSTEM,
                delay = 3L
            )
            .test()
            .await()
            .assertComplete()
    }
}
```